# Testing Closure Compiler output under Node.js

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, google-closure-compiler, vows

I'd like to use Vows to test DOM-free JavaScript code, ideally directly running against the compiled JS.
My Vows are written in CoffeeScript, but I'm not sure how to load my JS; I've tried just inlining it using `eval`:

```
vows = require "vows"
assert = require "assert"
eval('var e=this;function f(a,g){var c=a.split("."),b=e;!(c[0]in b)&&b.execScript&&b.execScript("var "+c[0]);for(var d;c.length&&(d=c.shift());)!c.length&&g!==void 0?b[d]=g:b=b[d]?b[d]:b[d]={}}function h(a){a.call(e)};(function(){var a;a={};h(function(){a=function(a){this.a=a};a.prototype.b=function(a){return this.a+a.a};f("Cl.LinearExpression",a);f("Cl.LinearExpression.prototype.plus",a.prototype.b)})}).call(this);');

vows
  .describe("Linear Expression")
  .addBatch
    "initialized with a number":
      topic: -> new Cl.LinearExpression 5

      "adds up with scalar": (cle) -> assert.equal 7, cle.plus 2

  .export(module)
```

but I get "ReferenceError: Cl is not defined".
Running the minified JS and `new Cl.LinearExpression(5);` in a browser console works fine, so the compiled code is okay.
What's the best way to load JS into node for testing by Vows?

Comment: You can inline JS with backticks, don't use eval for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a namespace problem; importing with

```
codes = require "../out/compiled.js"
for k,v of codes
  global[k] = v
```

adds all of the compiled JS objects to the current namespace, where they can be accessed in Vows.

Unfortunately, I still don't know why using `eval()` or backticks with the inlined contents of `compiled.js` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using `eval`, why not use Node's `require`? You can point to either a `.js` or `.coffee` file in a relative directory, like so:

```
Cl = require './cl.js'
```

In that file, add the line

```
module.exports = Cl
```

When the file is `require`d, the return value of the `require` is the module's `exports`.

Comment: I'd like to avoid having to declare `module.exports` in my compiled JS since I won't be running it as a node library. I did just try that though, and I get the error "Cl is not defined" with the stacktrace showing it from "cl.js". It seems like Node is evaluating the JS somehow differently than Chrome does.

Comment: You could also write `this.Cl = ...` (in the outermost scope). That will create a global named `Cl` in the browser, and an export named `Cl` in Node. Use `{Cl} = require './cl'` to access the exported object from you tests.

Comment: I'm not saying `Cl =` anywhere in my JS---it's being compiled by Google's Closure compiler (with advanced optimizations on) and some magic is going on that seems to work in the browser but not in node.

Comment: You might want to do your tests in a browser environment, then. If you use [js-test-driver](http://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/), you can run browser tests from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use backtick to embed javascript as-is.

```
`var e=this;function f(a,g){ ... `
```

Comment: I didn't know this, thanks. This is nicer to say than `eval()` but I get the same error.